# Maven build is not working for STS spring-tool-suite-3.7.2.RELEASE-e4.5.1-win32.zip

Tags: maven, spring-tool-suite

I just created a simple test maven quick start project in my Windows 7 PC.

getting

> CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for
>   plugin execution default-compile: PluginResolutionException: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

I have mapped manual maven home from local machine thought embedded version has the problem

Comment: Can you connect to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in a browser on that machine? It seems there is a connectivity problem.

Comment: hello David yes I can connect to repo link

Comment: If the browser works does not mean the maven can download things. In your browser there can be configured a proxy etc. which you need to do in Maven as well the user `settings.xml` is the thing you need to check for.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

This will make a clean install and update the dependencies